# ANTLR4 : no viable alternative at input error

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I created a sample grammer and generated java source codes and compile them and executed my sample grammer but I got an error like the below.

```
C:\devEnvironments\antlr>java org.antlr.v4.runtime.misc.TestRig mytest.RuleTest
column_spec -tree
aaa.bbb.ccc
^Z
line 1:0 no viable alternative at input 'aaa.bbb.ccc\r\n'
(column_spec aaa.bbb.ccc\r\n)
```

The following is my rule source code.

```
grammar RuleTest;

@header {
package mytest;
}


column_spec:
    ( ( schema_name DOT )? table_name DOT )? column_name ;

ID: 
    ( 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '_' | '$') ( 'A'..'Z' | 'a'..'z' | '_' | '$' | '0'..'9' )*
;

// identifiers ---  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/identifiers.html --------------
schema_name         : ID;
table_name          : ID;
engine_name         : ID;
column_name         : ID;
view_name           : ID;
parser_name         : ID;
index_name          : ID;
partition_name          : ID;
partition_logical_name      : ID;
constraint_symbol_name      : ID;
foreign_key_symbol_name     : ID;
collation_name          : ID;
event_name          : ID;
user_name           : ID;
function_name           : ID;
procedure_name          : ID;
server_name         : ID;
wrapper_name            : ID;
alias               : ( AS_SYM )? ANY_STRING;

ANY_STRING:
    ~(' ')+;

DOT : '.' ;
AS_SYM              : 'as';

WS  : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I don't know why '\r', '\n' characters are not skipped and why this error happens?
I used antlr 4.4 version.

Answer (score 1):

The `ANY_STRING` lexer rule matches your entire input. Since that's long than the 3 characters matched by the `ID` rule, it will always have precedence. You need to either remove that rule, or change it so it only matches one character (thus never the longest).

```
ANY_STRING_CHAR : ~' ';
```

Comment: And to augment Sams answer: create a rule `anyString` that matches one or more `ANY_STRING_CHAR`s and use it in places where you previously used `ANY_STRING`.